# git svn, how should I init my svn repo and synchronise with my existing git repo

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have currently working git repo at url_git and new svn repo at url_svn.

I want to use svn repo with git svn -plugin and I've cloned repo with:

```
git svn clone --username user url_svn/project_svn
```

and when I use for example

```
git svn rebase
or
git svn dcommit
```

It works just fine

And when I try to push my git repo to svn

```
git clone git_url/project_git
cd project_git
git svn init url_svn/project_svn
```

Fetch:

```
git svn fetch
        A       initial_commit
r1 = c9e1ab586b658f3f5518e3ed36e87ded675a4685 (refs/remotes/git-svn)
```

Rebase / dcommit:

```
git svn rebase
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history

git svn dcommit
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
Perhaps the repository is empty. at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 856.
```

What do I need to do to get this working?